# multicast to a String collection

Tags: apache-camel

Is there an easy may to send a message to many endpoints, defined in a `List<String>`?

For exemple, I would like to do :

```
from("file://c:/inbox").to(myStringList);
```

Comment: i think you should consider recipient list

Comment: Yep but recipientList seems to be for dynamically manage outputs during runtime. All I want is do a `to(str1, str2, str3, str4, ...)` (which is possible) but with a string list. If I have to use a recipient list for that, something is clearly missing in camel synthax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need to turn that list into an array as shown. Though doing this in pure Java is a bit ugly as the code shows:

```
String[] s = myStringList.toArray(new String[myStringList.size()]);
from("file://c:/inbox").to(s);
```

Comment: Woaw, an answer from Claus Ibsen himself! Thank you Master, your book is much better than the online doc.
Worked perfectly by the way.